# How do I search for a pattern within a paragraph of multiple sentences using regex in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I have a paragraph as `'Hello my name is xyz how may I help you today. <SOME MORE SENTNCES HERE> . Thanks for calling have a nice day. '` .
I want a RegEx for finding `'Hello my name is xyz how may I help you today'` and `'have a nice day'` in a complete paragraph in a single expression if that could be possible. Between these two phrases which I want to find can be any number of words/sentences.

Comment: What is the exact output you expect from the above?  Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: Yes pls show the output you want

Comment: I want to know whether these strings are present in the paragraph or not. Not any particular output interest me only whether it's in the paragraph or not.
I have an audio call transcription and I need to validate whether these string phrases were present in the transcription  or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to find matching strings. `re.findall` will return a list with the matches. You can then use an if statement to find if the list is not empty, and thus containing at least one match. Also do not forget to use the `re.IGNORECASE`, to ignore case  sensitive behavior. Below you find an example for both a match and not a match.

```
import re

txt = 'Hello my name is xyz how may I help you today. <SOME MORE SENTNCES HERE> . Thanks for calling have a nice day. '
negative_txt = 'Hello my name is xyz how may I help you today. <SOME MORE SENTNCES HERE> . Thanks for calling have a terrible day. '


print('for the txt')
my_name_is = re.findall('HeLlO mY nAmE is', txt, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
nice_day = re.findall('have a nice day', txt, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if my_name_is and nice_day:
    print("the sentences 'Hello my name is', and 'have a nice day', are present")
else:
    print("the sentence 'Hello my name is' or 'have a nice day', are NOT present")

print('for the negative txt')  
my_name_is = re.findall('Hello my name is', negative_txt, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
nice_day = re.findall('have a nice day', negative_txt, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if my_name_is and nice_day:
    print("the sentences 'Hello my name is', and 'have a nice day', are present")
else:
    print("the sentence 'Hello my name is' or 'have a nice day', are NOT present")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `.*`, where the `.` matches any character and the `*` is the zero-or-more operator.

```
Hello my name is .* how may I help you today.*have a nice day
```

Also, I guess you may want to add the `IGNORECASE` flag to your search.

The final code will be such this:

```py
import re
my_text = "Hello my name is xyz how may I help you today. <SOME MORE SENTNCES HERE> . Thanks for calling have a nice day."
my_regex = r"Hello my name is .* how may I help you today.*have a nice day"
if re.search(my_regex, my_text, re.IGNORECASE) :
    print("OK")
```